# Is there a location where one can download all of the gpx files for OSM?

Tags: openstreetmap, gpx, download

Where can I download **all the gpx file** in OSM.org website? Is there a package include all the gpx file? I don't want to download these gpx files one by one...

Comment: Wouldn't that result in an enormous (and hence very difficult to use/unusable) file?

Comment: exactly enormous. according to my estimation, they will be larger than 300GB. But these original gpx files are very useful to me because I want to build trajectories of users using these gpx files. I have tried to crawl these gpx files to my computer by a small program(I wrote it:P), but it is too slow to bear...I'm wondering why not the OSM.org just pack these original gpx files up and release it with routine update:(?(just like the osm file?)

Comment: I downloaded and installed QGIS 2.0. The plugin 'OSM open search' is missing.
It is neither found loadable from VIEW nor PLUGIN menu. It is also not in the
REPOSITORY window. How can I get it installed into the QGIS software?

Answer (score 1):

Here: http://downloads.cloudmade.com/ but note that data is updated on a half year interval!

Comment: thanks a lot!!!It really helps me(like the POI files). However, what I need in addition is the raw(original) gpx files uploaded by users in http://www.openstreetmap.org/traces. But these files are seperated and not convenient to download them all.  I have tried to crawl these gpx files to my computer by a small program in java(I wrote it:P), but it is too slow to bear...I'm wondering why not the OSM.org just pack these original gpx files up and release it with routine update:(?(just like the osm file?)

Comment: This service is unfortunately discontinued by Cloudmade.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. All of the GPX Traces uploaded to OSM can be found in the [planet.gpx](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.gpx) file at http://planet.openstreetmap.org/gps/

Comment: thx for your answer. However, these files only include points without time label(maybe they are useful to other developers)which is very useful to me. What I want to build is a kind of trajectories of users, which is in a certain order of points.

Comment: In a word, I need all the file in http://www.openstreetmap.org/traces. So I am wondering is there a package for these files with which I don't need to download them one by one.